# wso2 Greg - Service Registry and Discover with Rest

Tags: web-services, rest, wso2-api-manager, wso2

I have all wso2 products, but I don't understand how I can use Governance Registry in conjunction with rest webservices.

For example: I published a Rest Webservice in Governance, and now I want to use the service discovery to get the endpoint for this Webservice.

It's possible to do this with wso2 products?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With WSO2 Governance Registry, you can discover endpoint details in three different ways: As example, if you are using WSO2 ESB([integration scenarios for Governance](https://cnapagoda.blogspot.com/2016/05/g-reg-and-esb-integration-scenarios-for.html))

- Share Registry space with both ESB and G-Reg
- Use G-Reg to push artifacts into ESB node
- ESB pull artifact from the G-Reg

Since you have already created a Rest Service in the G-Reg side, you can retrieve Endpoint details using Governance Rest API. It has an inbuilt functionality to retrieve Endpoint associated with a given RestService instance. You can find more details from [this doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance540/Governance+REST+API#GovernanceRESTAPI-Endpoints).